# Exceptions handling for floats c++

Tags: c++, exception

Hey I'm trying to have my code throw up an error if anything other than a numerical value is input by the user.

This is what I have done so far but when I run the program and input a character instead of a number it just skips through the rest of the inputs and outputs calculations without actually throwing up any error message.

```
#include "classes.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
//class constructor
thevenin::thevenin()
{
    Resistance_1 = 1;
    Resistance_2 = 1;
    Resistance_3 = 1;
    Voltage_1 = 1;
    Voltage_2 = 1;


}
//empty class destructor
thevenin::~thevenin()
{

}
//output script for One loop problems
void thevenin::One_loop_thev(float tr1o, float tv1v)
{
    //inputs



    if (cin.fail()) //checking whether failbit or badbit is set
    {
        cout<<"error";
        cin.clear(); //sets a new value for the stream's internal error state flags.
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n'); //ignores rest of the input ..
    }
    else;

            cout<<"Please enter the value of R1"<<endl;
            cin>>Resistance_1;
            cout<<"Please enter the value of R2"<<endl;
            cin>>Resistance_2;
            cout<<"Please enter the value of R3"<<endl;
            cin>>Resistance_3;
            cout<<"Please enter the value of V1"<<endl;
            cin>>Voltage_1;

            //calculations
            tv1v = (Voltage_1 * Resistance_3)/ (Resistance_1 + Resistance_3);
            tr1o = Resistance_2 + ((Resistance_1*Resistance_3)/(Resistance_1+Resistance_3));

            cout<<"The Thevenin equivalent resistance is: "<<tr1o<<"ohms"<<endl;
            cout<<"The Thevenin equivalent voltage is: "<<tv1v<<"volts"<<endl;
```

I was just wondering how I should adjust the `if(cin.fail())` statement to work with my code.

Comment: @MaksimSolovjov I adjusted as suggested and it still just follows through with the calculations instead of throwing an error :/

Comment: Do you mean to check the validity of input for `Resistance_1...Voltage_1`? Because you're checking it before that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stream will encounter an error when you try to read in values, so you cannot check for errors before your `cin`s.

One way to get errors thrown is to tell `iostream` to throw them for you:

```
cin.exceptions(istream::failbit);
```

However, then you should handle the errors that arise. A small demo:

```
 #include <iostream>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 #include <limits>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

 using namespace std;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

 int main () {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
     cin.exceptions(istream::failbit);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
     float a;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
     while (!cin.eof()) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
         try {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
             cin >> a;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
             cout << a<< '\n';                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
          } catch (istream::failure& e) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
             cout << "bad input\n";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
             cin.clear();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
             cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
         }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
      }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  }
```

So, for your code (**Edited to add retries**):

```
//output script for One loop problems
void thevenin::One_loop_thev(float tr1o, float tv1v)
{
    cin.exceptions(istream::failbit); // throw errors

    while (true) {
        try {
            cout<<"Please enter the value of R1"<<endl;
            cin>>Resistance_1;
            cout<<"Please enter the value of R2"<<endl;
            cin>>Resistance_2;
            cout<<"Please enter the value of R3"<<endl;
            cin>>Resistance_3;
            cout<<"Please enter the value of V1"<<endl;
            cin>>Voltage_1;

            //calculations
            tv1v = (Voltage_1 * Resistance_3)/ (Resistance_1 + Resistance_3);
            tr1o = Resistance_2 + ((Resistance_1*Resistance_3)/(Resistance_1+Resistance_3));

            cout<<"The Thevenin equivalent resistance is: "<<tr1o<<"ohms"<<endl;
            cout<<"The Thevenin equivalent voltage is: "<<tv1v<<"volts"<<endl;

            return; // break out of the loop
        }
        catch (istream::failure& e) {
            cout<<"error";
            cin.clear(); //sets a new value for the stream's internal error state flags.
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n'); //ignores rest of the input ..
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot guys I'm on my way to work just now so I'll try rearranging it when I get home and I'll let you know if it works

Comment: That worked fantastically mate. it throws up an error message now. Absolute champion. Would there be anyway to tell it to restart the script... ie go back to "pleas enter the value of r1"

Comment: Glad I could help. I've update the example with a very basic way to have retries, hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

```
if (cin.fail()) //checking whether failbit or badbit is set
    {
        cout<<"error";
        cin.clear(); //sets a new value for the stream's internal error state flags.
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n'); //ignores rest of the input ..
    }
    else//;<--- why semicolon?
{
            cout<<"Please enter the value of R1"<<endl;
            cin>>Resistance_1;
            cout<<"Please enter the value of R2"<<endl;
            cin>>Resistance_2;
            cout<<"Please enter the value of R3"<<endl;
            cin>>Resistance_3;
            cout<<"Please enter the value of V1"<<endl;
            cin>>Voltage_1;

            //calculations
            tv1v = (Voltage_1 * Resistance_3)/ (Resistance_1 + Resistance_3);
            tr1o = Resistance_2 + ((Resistance_1*Resistance_3)/(Resistance_1+Resistance_3));

            cout<<"The Thevenin equivalent resistance is: "<<tr1o<<"ohms"<<endl;
            cout<<"The Thevenin equivalent voltage is: "<<tv1v<<"volts"<<endl;
}
```

is this what you meant? I got rid of the semicolon after the else..

apart from that try simple try-catch statement...
Also, where are you passing value to cin? (where are you getting it). show us the code for that is well please.

Comment: `cin` comes from a combination of `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std;` in the posted code.  Not pretty, but as defined.

Comment: have you tried removing the semicolon as I suggested and adding the braces?

Comment: what I meant by where cin comes from is where you call the command - you call `cin.fail()` before inputing values by `cin>>resistance_1`. you should check for cin.fail() after user inputs the values, not before.